# Multiple dropdown menus - one Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am hoping to create a form with multiple dropdown selection menus.
I'm pretty new at JQuery and was hoping someone could help me to figure out my problem.
I'm trying to figure out how to get each list to function individually, without having to duplicate the JQuery code. Is this possible? Here is my current codepen : http://codepen.io/kelseyhisek/pen/HbGDm

```
<h1>Dead Simple Dropmenu</h1>
<div class="ds_select">
  <div class="ds_label ds_placeholder">Select me...</div>
  <ul class="ds_list">
      <li><a href="#what">What?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#its">It's</a></li>
      <li><a href="#that">That</a></li>
      <li><a href="#easy">Easy?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="ds_select">
  <div class="ds_label ds_placeholder">Select me...</div>
  <ul class="ds_list">
      <li><a href="#what">What?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#its">It's</a></li>
      <li><a href="#that">That</a></li>
      <li><a href="#easy">Easy?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700);
body{
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Lato;
  color:#999
}
.ds_select,
.ds_select *
    {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
    }
.ds_placeholder{
  padding:15px 18px;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  z-index:2;
}

.ds_select
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 1;
        width: 200px;
        max-height:50px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 3px solid #5e5e5e;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #444444;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: 0;
      overflow:hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
       transition:all 0.3s
    }


    .ds_select:before,
    .ds_select:after
        {
            content: "\25B2";
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 12px;
            font-size: 7px;
        }

    .ds_select:after
            {
                content: "\25BC";
                top: 20px;
            }


    .ds_select:hover,
    .ds_select.open{ border-color: #000000; }
    .ds_select.open{max-height:600px }


    .ds_select .ds_label
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;

        }


    .ds_select .ds_list
        {

            margin-top: -30px;
            opacity:0;
            width: inherit;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 0;
          transition:all 0.2s
        }


        .ds_select.open .ds_list { opacity:1;
         margin-top: 0px;}



        .ds_select .ds_list li a
            {
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                display:block;  
                position: relative;
                padding: 10px 10px;
                list-style-type: none;
                color:#999;
                text-decoration:none
            }


            .ds_select li a:hover
                {
                    background: #eee;
                    color: #000;

                }
$('.ds_placeholder').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('.ds_select').hasClass('open'))
    $('.ds_select').removeClass('open');
  else
     $('.ds_select').addClass('open');
});

//Or just remove this and go to link

$('.ds_list a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.ds_placeholder').text($(this).text());
  $('.ds_select').removeClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so the problem is that inside your click handlers your selecting ".ds_select" which is looking globally for *all* divs with the class .ds_select. It then adds the open class to *all* of them. I think what you want is this inside your click handler:

```
 $('.ds_placeholder').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var $dropdown = $(this).parents('.ds_select');

     $dropdown.toggleClass('open');
 });
```

By the same token you'll want to update the placeholder like this:

```
 $('.ds_list a').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $dropdown = $(this).parents('.ds_select');
   var $placeholder = $dropdown.find(".ds_placeholder");

   $placeholder.text($(this).text());
   $dropdown.removeClass('open');
 });
```

Looks like there's also an issue with the dropdown pushing the other dropdown to the bottom;

I think you could fix that by adding `vertical-align: top;` to your ds_select class, but I'm not so hot with CSS. So maybe somebody else will chime in.

**Update** used toggleClass for simplicity hat-tip Steve Sanders

Comment: You can simplify this further by using `toggleClass`